# Create Streaming PushTopic using REST API?

Tags: apex, rest-api, streaming-api, pushtopic

Salesforce Streaming API documentation gives the examples of creating PushTopics through the developer console by running some APEX code. Is there a way to create PushTopics programmatically using REST API? If yes, then how? If no, then does it mean that I will have to upload this APEX for each sobject in the salesforce account?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can create a PushTopic via the REST API.

Based on the [Create a Record](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_sobject_create.htm) example and [PushTopic](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/pushtopic.htm):

```
curl https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/PushTopic/ 
    -H "Authorization: Bearer token -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
    -d "@newpushtopic.json"
```

**Request Body newpushtopic.json**

```
{
    "Name" : "Account",
    "Query" : "SELECT Id FROM Account",
    "ApiVersion" : 32.0,
    "NotifyForOperationCreate" : true,
    "NotifyForOperationUpdate" : true,
    "NotifyForOperationUndelete" : true,
    "NotifyForOperationDelete" : true,
    "NotifyForFields" : "All",
}
```

Answer (score -1):

is their any specific requirement of implementing Pushtopic code using REST api ?

If you just don't want to copy paste code every time in developer console for pushtopic creation. make use of an apex class and invoke that class from a command button from your desired location.

Comment: When I deploy my code to a target org, the pushtopics needs to be created for all objects. Hence the question.